# Convert Venn diagram to grob?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Hi there are several ways to convert R base plots to grob object, however I can't seem to get venn diagrams from the VennDiagram package to do this. I tried two different methods but both failed.  Any ideas? thanks!

```
library ( VennDiagram )
library(ggplotify)
library(gridGraphics)

venn.plot <- draw.pairwise.venn(
    area1 = 100,
    area2 = 70,
    cross.area = 30,
    category = c("First", "Second"),
    cat.pos = c(0, 180),
    euler.d = TRUE,
    sep.dist = 0.03,
    rotation.degree = 45
);




grab_grob <- function(){
    grid.echo()
    grid.grab()
}

grid.draw(venn.plot )
g <- grab_grob()
p1 <- as.grob( venn.plot )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `venn.plot` object is a `gList`, a list of grobs. You can use that object directly. If you want `p1` with class `grob`, you can substitute the last line with:

```
> p1 <- grobTree(venn.plot)
```

Then,

```
> is.grob(p1)
[1] TRUE
> class(p1)
[1] "gTree" "grob"  "gDesc"
```

Comment: thanks this is perfect.  Just in case someone else is reading. I can go one step further and convert this to a ggplot object `as.ggplot(p1) + ggtitle ("gtitle")`